# Problema en anidación de objetos en MongoDB y Node

Tags: nodejs, ionic, mongodb, mongoose, postman

Estoy haciendo una aplicación, tengo un principal Schema el cual es Post, este tiene la siguientes características:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({

    created: {
        type: Date
    },
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario']
    },
    descripcion: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La descripción es necesaria']
    },
    video: {
        type: String
    },
    secciones: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Seccion',
        required: [true, 'Debe de existir una referencia a una seccion']
    }] });
```

Yo veo todo bien, pero al momento de hacer la prueba en PostMan, cuando ingreso el id de alguna seccion en el parametro Secciones me funciona pero solo con un id, y quisiera poder ingresar varias Secciones.

Es decir, que yo por PostMan le pueda enviar **5dacaa63ed310b0fa7ee, 5dacaa63ed310bcfa7ed** y el me deje.

Por el momento me da error.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el método de tu controlador con el cual procesas la solicitud que envías desde Postman? Dices: *Por momento me da error*, ¿podrías también mostrar el error que te da?. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es porque cuando le llega a `Mongoose` no llega como tipo `ObjecId` sino como `String`.

Para solucionar esto deberías parsear el `String` en un ObjectId.

Solución:

```
 const { Types: { ObjectId} } = require('mongoose')
 let secciones = ['5dacaa63ed310b0fa7ee', '5dacaa63ed310bcfa7ed']
 let mongoObjectIds = secciones.map(id => ObjectId(id))
 // [ ObjectId("5dacaa63ed310b0fa7ee"), ObjectId("5dacaa63ed310bcfa7ed")]
```

Espero que con esta solución pueda resolverte el problema.

Un saludo